# Options for accessing SSRS reports through Power BI Service

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I have a number of reports I have deployed to an SSRS report server in my intranet. The reports display data in tables & a matrix with some other summary information in the report header and footer. The report data source is SQL Server 2014.

I now have a requirement to have these reports accessible through the Power BI service. When accessed through the power BI service, the data is expected to be up to date.

Is the above requirement possible, is the kind of configuration currently supported.  If yes, would someone point me to the available options.

If this isn't possible, would someone point me to documented evidence saying so such that I can bring it forward to management as official documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your requirement to 1) present links to the SSRS reports from the PowerBi Service reports?  or the data (on prem) that SSRS uses to generate the reports needs to be available to PowerBi Service (external)?

Comment: @Taterhead the report needs to be displayed in a power BI service dashboard the way an SSRS report can be displayed in an asp.net web app using the report-viewer control. and should be connected to the live SQL server data source.

Comment: I think the answer is going to be no, but I need to research more and provide you references.  However, there are compelling reasons to migrate to the service.  Unless your SSRS reports are paged (user can scroll back and forth through items) and these reports aggregate/group your SQL data, then you will want to move them to Power Bi.  But we would need to know more details in your question.

Comment: yes the reports are paged, can be like 20 pages at time and indeed some have groupings

Comment: I was exploring this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4136/pinning-a-sql-server-reporting-services-report-to-power-bi/ but i have not been able to successfully register the connection/integration  between power BI and SSRS

Answer (score 0):

Power Bi Service Dashboards can contain pinned Reporting Services items.  The following requirements need to be met:

1. Your will need SSRS 2016 or later.
2. Your SSRS 2016 will need to be integrated Azure Active Directory and Power BI.  Details on how to do this are too long for this post ([but can be found here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/power-bi-report-server-integration-configuration-manager))
3. Your browser allows pop ups from your report server site.
4. Your reports will need to use stored credentials to get the automatic refresh requirement.
5. Only top level items can be pinned.  Nothing that is nested in a data region (table or list) can be pinned.

Instructions on how to pin an item in your dashboard can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pin-reporting-services-items-to-power-bi-dashboards#bkmk_to_pin).  More details on the SSRS pinned items integration with Power Bi requirements can be found [in the online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pin-reporting-services-items-to-power-bi-dashboards).